# how to fetch the string starts with &abc and ends with &

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

i like to know how to fetch the specific string which starts with &abc and ends with &. I tried with had prefix and sufix . but this is not new line ,

&xyz;123:183:184:142&
&abc;134:534:435:432&
&qwe;323:535:234:532&

my code :

```
NSMutableArray *substrings = [NSMutableArray new];
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:s];
[scanner scanUpToString:@"&abc" intoString:nil]; //
NSString *substring = nil;
[scanner scanString:@"&abc" intoString:nil]; // Scan the # character
if([scanner scanUpToString:@"&" intoString:&substring]) {
   // If the space immediately followed the &, this will be skipped
   [substrings addObject:substring];
   NSLog(@"substring is :%@",substring);
}
// do something with substrings
[substrings release];
```

---

how to make "scanner scanUpToString:@"&abc" and count ":"==3 till "#"????  can help me

Comment: string are in array or ?

Comment: ya its in array i ll put in the array

Comment: so your array is as `@[@"&abcxx&", @"anoop", @"&abcApple&", @"@abcBox"];` And your filtered array shuld contain.. `&abcxx&, &abcApple&`

Comment: Try this one `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF like [c]'&abc*&'"];
    NSArray *filteredArray = [initialArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"&xyz;123:183:184:142&",
                    @"&abc;134:534:435:432&",
                    @"&qwe;323:535:234:532&",
                    @"& I am not in it",
                    @"&abc I am out &" ,nil];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self BEGINSWITH[cd] %@ AND self ENDSWITH[cd] %@",@"&abc",@"&"];

    NSLog(@"Sorted Array %@",[arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]);
    NSArray *sortedArray = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    NSMutableArray *finalResult = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
    for(NSString *string in sortedArray)
    {
        NSString *content = string;
        NSRange range1 = [content rangeOfString:@"&abc"];
        if(range1.length > 0)
            content = [content stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range1 withString:@""];

        NSRange range2 = [content rangeOfString:@"&"];
        if(range2.length > 0)
            content = [content stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range2 withString:@""];

        [finalResult addObject:content];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",finalResult);
```

Comment: it work fine if there is space " &" (self ENDSWITH) . check if "&qwe;323:535:234:532&" this is not working in your code

Comment: so do you want all the strings either starts with '&abcæ' or ends with '&', right @dilipanand

Comment: it will match characters/words your enter in filter string, if you want put ' &' then it will only return matching not ending with '&' but only ending with ' &'

Comment: string between '&abc' and '&'?

Comment: ya m i need only the string betwwen "&abc" and "&" i did everything this is my last task , can u help me

Comment: you are welcome @dilipanand, actually your question was not clear initially, thats why..

Comment: urs works fine in array , but hw to make this in NSstring , bcoz my inputstream is in string

Comment: anyhow you u need to split your string to array, there is no other way with string.

Comment: NSString*myString =@"&abc;134:534:435 &qwe;323:535:234:532& &I am nott in it& &abc I am out &";
NSArray*arr=[myString componentsSeparatedByString:@""];


its not working if i try in this manner

Comment: of course it will not, because it can not detect multiple occurance of string. thats why you need to split your string for further operation, may be by length, you can do it.

Comment: if i splitting the string "componentsSeperatedby:@"&"", my & getting deleted do u have idea idea how to split without deleting "&"??

Comment: using NSRange you can get string.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
- (BOOL)isValidString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSRegularExpression *regularExpression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^&abc.*&$" options:0 error:NULL];
    NSTextCheckingResult *result = [regularExpression firstMatchInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
    return (result != nil);
}
```